# Automate pull from raspberry when a push is performed

Tags: github, raspberry-pi, github-actions, cicd, aws-iot

I have some raspberry pi that are connected to the network via 4g dongles.
It is possible for me to reach these devices using the AWS IoT service.

I would need to automate the update of a repository on these sensors. The idea would be that when a push is made, the raspberries would notice the update and automatically make the pull.
I thought about using GitHub actions, but the problem is that the only solution I have found is to make a connection via SSH, which is not possible for me to do.

Are there other ways to automate this process (besides creating a script on the crontab)? Is there any AWS native methods to perform it?

I tried to implement it using GitHub Actions and WebHooks, but the problem is that I can't connect to the raspberry directly from github.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it is to use either MQTT or WebSockets on your Raspberry PI to connect to an IoT platform (can be AWS or something else).

You didn't say what do you use to read your sensors? On a PI I would probably use Node.js but it can really be anything (Python, JAVA, C++) that supports MQTT or WebSockets.

AWS IoT uses MQTT and there is a full tutorial for Node.js/Python for PI [here is the link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/connecting-to-existing-device.html).
There is a fair bit to go through but I don't see why it wouldn't work. It's exactly what you have asked for, a native AWS solution to communicate with their IoT cloud through a Raspberry PI.

If you just want to run a quick test/proof of concept and check if your setup would work for a bi-directional communication you are more than welcome to try a small platform I have cobbled together for Arduino DIY IoT stuff but works fine with Node & PI. Just ping me a message on [chipchop.io](https://chipchop.io) and I'll give you access and send you a Node.js test client code.